# ASP.NET Sharing a user control/web page logic with multiple web applications

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application, which has a user control and web page logic to be used on multiple web applications. The reason I want to do this is that I want the other web applications to reference this one since the html/css of their web pages varies.

First of all I wanted to ask if this is possible since it is a web application and not a class library.

Secondly if it is possible how do I refrence the web page logic to the htmls of the other web applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding the Web User Control to a Class Library and referencing that Class Library from the website ?

Here are instructions by Haacked on how to add a User Control to a Class Library: http://haacked.com/archive/2006/02/07/AddingWebUserControlToAClassLibraryInVS.NET2005.aspx

---

Also here is a post by Guthrie about *[Building Re-Usable ASP.NET User Control and Page Libraries with VS 2005](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/28/423888.aspx)* and I think it's worth a look.

**[Update]**

I found a better tutorial on [Creating and Using User Control Libraries](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UserControls/UserControls.aspx).  I think that this article is more concise than the other one by Guthrie (*also this one is also by Guthrie*)

Comment: Hi, Scott's article metions the same thing as I did. So I should update it to be sure enough it will work.

Comment: The Scott Guthrie article is about VS2005 RTM. It only had web sites, not Web Application Projects. Even when he uses the term "Web Application Project", he's talking about Web Site Projects. The technique he uses will not work with an actual Web Application Project.

Comment: The second Guthrie article is about Web Application Projects (http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UserControls/UserControls.aspx). In fact, it's part of the site they created when Web Application Projects were still an add-in (or should I say, "add-back-in").

Answer (score 0):

Compile and deploy your asp.net website which will produce one assembly per code-behind.

Pick the assembly of the code-behind class you want to re-use and drop it into the \bin folder of your 2nd web-app in which you want to reuse it.

Now this assembly will have a partial class which you can merge with the code-behind of an existing web-page. Just ensure the naming hierarchy are matching.